# Replace Conditional Row Values By Group in R

Tags: r

I have a table

```
ID         RATES
 1          0.01
 1            0
 1            0
 1            0
 2          0.05
 2          0.05
 2          0.01
 2            0
 3            0
 3            0
 3            0
```

Ideally, I want to create a new column called n_rates which replace the 0 values in rate column by group (ID) and conditions.

```
Condition 1 - If at least one rate IN (0.01, 0.015, 0.05) for this ID THEN replace all 0 values by the most rate values (e.g. if for this ID, 0.01 appears more than 0.05 then replace 0 with 0.01. Only rates == 0 rows can be replaced)

Condition 2 - If rates NOT IN (0.01, 0.015, 0.05) then make no changes to the rows
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function called by `%>% do(...)`

```
myfun <- function(df) {
    targets <- c(0.01, 0.015, 0.05)
    if (any(unique(df$RATES) %in% targets)) {
        val <- as.numeric(names(head(sort(-table(df$RATES[df$RATES > 0])), 1)))
        df %>%
                mutate(RATES = ifelse(RATES==0, val, RATES))
    } else {
        df
    }
}

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  do(myfun(.))

# A tibble: 11 x 2
# Groups: ID [3]
      # ID  RATES
   # <int>  <dbl>
 # 1     1 0.0100
 # 2     1 0.0100
 # 3     1 0.0100
 # 4     1 0.0100
 # 5     2 0.0500
 # 6     2 0.0500
 # 7     2 0.0100
 # 8     2 0.0500
 # 9     3 0.    
# 10     3 0.    
# 11     3 0.
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text="ID         RATES
 1          0.01
 1            0
 1            0
 1            0
 2          0.05
 2          0.05
 2          0.01
 2            0
 3            0
 3            0
 3            0", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find the mode , the most frequency value for each group , I am using dplyr `group_by` here

function from [Ken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/7964527)

```
Mode <- function(x) {
    ux <- unique(x)
    ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

---

```
library(dplyr)
df1=dt[dt$RATES%in%c(0.05,0.01),]%>%group_by(ID)%>%summarise(Value=Mode(RATES)) 

dt=merge(dt,df1,on='ID',all.x=T)# merge back the result to original dt    
dt$RATES[dt$RATES==0]=dt$Value[dt$RATES==0] # assign the value only if the RATES equal to 0

dt$RATES[is.na(dt$RATES)]=0 # fill NA back to 0 
dt$Value=NULL# drop the helper column
```

---

Result

```
dt

   ID RATES
1   1  0.01
2   1  0.01
3   1  0.01
4   1  0.01
5   2  0.05
6   2  0.05
7   2  0.05
8   2  0.01
9   3  0.00
10  3  0.00
11  3  0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

For a one-liner `data.table` answer, and using [Ken's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode/8189441#8189441) function:

```
Mode <- function(x) {
    ux <- unique(x)
    ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Rates := ifelse(Rates==0 & any(Rates!=0), 
                             Mode(Rates[Rates!=0]), Rates), by = ID]
df

#ID Rates
#1  0.01
#1  0.01
#1  0.01
#1  0.01
#2  0.05
#2  0.05
#2  0.01
#2  0.05
#3  0.00
#3  0.00
#3  0.00
```